# Jquery ajax running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have this problem. I am using a plugin named jRating, it is esentially a rating system in jquery. My problem is, that `onClick`, the ajax request fires **twice**.

After searching a lot, I tried those things:

1. I checked and double checked that the `$(document).ready(function(){}` and the jQuery shortcut `$(function() {});` is not twice in the page.
2. I also checked that the id of the call is unique.

So, here is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#rating").jRating({
            step:true,
            length : 5,
            canRateAgain : true,
            nbRates : 3,
            onClick : function(element,rate) {

                var data = (rate, 1);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'application/index/rate',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    async:false,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: rate,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('SUBMIT WORKS');

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        console.log('There is error while submit');

                    }

                });  

            }
        });
```

**pHTML:**

```
<div id="rating" data-average="<?=$average //note that this is working everytime!?>" data-id="1"></div>
```

Thanks for any inputs!

EDIT: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Je79U/ ;

To recreate the problem, click run, then go to console/network, clear all contents, then click anywhere on the yellow/orange bar, to rate, and see what happens. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: please provide fiddle link

Comment: ok, i`ll try to do a fiddle, be right back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with reference of http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/ , already jRating will work as ajax. So, that it takes ajax running twice

Please check their demo website clearly.

In that once you rate it will update the records to http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/php/jRating.php

and use the following version of jRating
https://github.com/alpixel/jRating

Comment: yup. This was it. Solved it! Thanks a lot!